# Linux Server out of Disk Space

Tags: linux, du, df

When I run some commands I get 'out of space' messages.  I looked around the Internet for ways to diagnose the issue.

I ran `df`:

```
adam@nas:/$ df
Filesystem            1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdf1              30257960  28769436         0 100% /
udev                    3982180         4   3982176   1% /dev
tmpfs                   1609804       632   1609172   1% /run
none                       5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                    4024504         0   4024504   0% /run/shm
overflow                   1024       212       812  21% /tmp
tank                  177356416       256 177356160   1% /mnt/tank
tank/CrashplanBackups 326836352 149480192 177356160  46% /mnt/tank/CrashplanBackups
tank/Downloads        178973440   1617280 177356160   1% /mnt/tank/Downloads
tank/Media            724196224 546840064 177356160  76% /mnt/tank/Media
tank/Photography      258230528  80874368 177356160  32% /mnt/tank/Photography
tank/XBMC             177646464    290304 177356160   1% /mnt/tank/XBMC
```

`/dev/sdf1` is full. It's a 32GB SD Card

I then ran `du`:

```
adam@nas:/$ sudo du --max-depth 1 -x -h
0   ./run
8.4M    ./sbin
1.9G    ./usr
0   ./tmp
0   ./dev
42M ./etc
0   ./sys
4.0K    ./lib64
16K ./media
171M    ./boot
2.5M    ./home
550M    ./var
4.0K    ./selinux
4.0K    ./srv
16K ./lost+found
8.7M    ./bin
1.2G    ./lib
18K ./mnt
60K ./root
0   ./proc
4.0K    ./opt
3.8G    .
```

So there is a massive difference.  I read about [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) so I ran:

```
adam@nas:/$ df -i
Filesystem               Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdf1               1913840 251600   1662240   14% /
udev                     995545    562    994983    1% /dev
tmpfs                   1006126    495   1005631    1% /run
none                    1006126      4   1006122    1% /run/lock
none                    1006126      1   1006125    1% /run/shm
overflow                1006126      7   1006119    1% /tmp
tank                  354712597     11 354712586    1% /mnt/tank
tank/CrashplanBackups 354712816    230 354712586    1% /mnt/tank/CrashplanBackups
tank/Downloads        354712645     59 354712586    1% /mnt/tank/Downloads
tank/Media            354714253   1667 354712586    1% /mnt/tank/Media
tank/Photography      354804713  92127 354712586    1% /mnt/tank/Photography
tank/XBMC             354717700   5114 354712586    1% /mnt/tank/XBMC
```

I also read about file descriptors and deleted files.

On running

```
lsof | grep "deleted"
```

nothing is returned.  Restarting the server does not free any space up.  How can I get my disk space back?  This is on Ubuntu 12.04 and is a NAS.

- It has 6 drives in total.
- 1x 32GB SD for the linux install
- 5x HD which use ZFS and is mounted in /mnt/tank

Comment: Did you already run a `fsck`? Maybe your filesystem is broken. And for identifying large files/directory there is a nice interactive tool: `ncdu`.

Comment: did you run lsof as root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have too many files in `/tmp`.  Because the disk was full at boot, you can see that a `tmpfs` was mounted in `/tmp` so you can write *something* to that location.  The `du` command can't see what is there because this `tmpfs` is in the way.  You can get around this by bind mounting `/` somewhere so you can look at it without any of the other mount points in the way:

```
sudo mount --bind / /mnt/foo
du -xh --max-depth=1 /mnt/foo
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it wasn't the tmp files but was another folder. Not sure why the files got into the state but I have now freed up 24GB of space.